# Highcharts, как yAxis значение сделать шагами день и час?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

У меня значение массива ( для Highcharts графика ) в секундах. Мне нужен вот такой результат: ( yAxis должен быт вот таким )

https://prnt.sc/q0wzgv

Я попробовал вот так, но в этом результате нет часы:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    yAxis: {

        min: 0,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                var median = this.value;
              var day = '';
              var midDay = '';
              var hour = '';
              var result = '';

                if (Math.floor( median / 86400 ) > 0) {
                day = Math.round(median / 86400);
                result += day + ' d ';
              } else {
                if (Math.floor( median / 42400 ) > 0) {
                  midDay = Math.round(median / 42400);
                  result += midDay + ' h ';
                } else {
                    if (Math.floor( median / 3600 ) > 0) {
                    hour = Math.round(median / 3600);
                    result += hour + ' h ';
                  } else {
                    result += median + ' s';
                  }
                                }
             }   


              return result;
            }
        }

    },

    series: [{
        data: [38369.5, 101080, 36300.5, 18517, 271700, 310215]

    }]
});
```

https://prnt.sc/q0x0i7

Вот здесь можете тестировать:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/

Помогите пожалуйста, кто знает. Благодарю заранее!

Comment: ну дак исправьте свою функцию, чтобы были часы. Почему вы выделяете целые дни, а остальное в ветку `else` запихиваете? Выделите дни, из остатка определите часы, а далее минуты и секунды при необходимости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторю свой комментарий к вопросу. Вы почему-то странным образом строите алгоритм перевода секунд в дни  и часы. Если у вас больше чем один день, то вы просто выводите дни и на этом конец. Хотя надо идти дальше и считать часы, минуты, секунды.

Если предположить, что градация на оси может быть разной, то чтобы вывести метку состоящую из двух наиболее значимых величин можно использовать примерно такой подход.

```js
var values = [38369.5, 101080, 36300.5, 18517, 271700, 310215, 605,0];


var labels = values.map(function(s){
     var d = Math.floor(s / 60 / 60 / 24); s %= 60*60*24;
     var h = Math.floor(s / 60/ 60); s %= 60*60;
     var m = Math.floor(s / 60); s %= 60;
     
     if(d) return `${d} days ${h} hours`;
     if(h) return `${h} hours ${m} min`;
     if(m) return `${m} min ${s} sec`;
     return `${s} sec`;     
});

console.log(labels);
```

такой способ будет универсален вне для возможных величин, хоть будут там целые дни попадаться, либо время только часами будет ограничено.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужен чтобы yAxis был именно так, как в скриншоте: https://prnt.sc/q0wzgv
0s, 12h, 1d 12h, 2d, 2d 12h и так далее.

Похоже этот свойство ( formatter: ) мне не поможет.

Comment: @TurarbekBoytov оно тоже пригодится, но тогда надо смотреть в сторону настройки фиксированных меток на оси, в частности, попробуйте [`tickInterval`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval) установить в 12*60*60

Comment: Cпасибо @teran за помощь, свойство tickInterval и ваше скрипт заработало. thumb up.